# Update each item in state onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update each item in the state by clicking a button. The initial state is FALSE (isSelected) for each item, if users do a onClick event on the button class div it should update the state (isSelected) of the current item to TRUE, but I'm not figuring out how to accomplish this.

EDITED: It should update only one item per click for example if I hit the button for `ID: 1` of `firsItem` it should change `isSelected` state to `true` only for `ID: 1`

This is an example of my code (how a I think it should be)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listItems: [{
        name: 'firstItem',
        itemOptionSelector: [{
          id: 1,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          isSelected: false
        },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'secondItem',
        itemOptionSelector: [{
          id: 1,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          isSelected: false
        },
        ]
      }
      ]
    }
  }

  selectItemClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      listItems: [{itemOptionSelector: [{isSelected: true}]}]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {listItems} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {listItems.map(item => {
          <div className="button" onClick={this.selectItemClickHandler}>{item.name}</div>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem in it

Comment: You need to use the index and pass in onClick event to update the state of the current item

Comment: Do you want every item in `itemOptionSelector` set `isSelected`  to true?

Comment: It should update only each per click for example if I hit the button for ID: 1 of  firsItem it should change isSelected state to true only for ID: 1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not clear what you are trying to do. You're not rendering your "sub-items" (or options), so there's no way currently to know which option should be changed to the selected state.

Generally, you update an array state like this:

```
state = {
  items: [
    { isSelected: false, name: 'first' },
    { isSelected: false, name: 'second' },
    { isSelected: false, name: 'third' },
  ]
};

// ...

handleItemClick = (item, index) => {
  const items = this.state.items.slice();
  items[index] = { ...item, isSelected: !item.isSelected };
  this.setState({ items });
};

render() {
  return this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
    <div onClick={() => this.handleItemClick(item, index)}>{item.name}</div>);
}
```

Comment: I was going to post exactly that, it's not clear what item needs to be updated.

Comment: @technophyle, you code is not update isSelected under itemOptionSelector, instead it added new property of isSelected as a sibling of itemOptionSelector.

Comment: @Khabir As I already answered, it's not possible to update that property based on the given code, so I put a general approach of updating state arrays.

Comment: @technophyle, I understand but I believe question is asked for updating under each item. Anyway, never mind please. I just wanted clear about that. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this complete example. Basically you had issue in setting state on click handler.

```
selectItemClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      listItems: [{itemOptionSelector: [{isSelected: true}]}]
    })
  }
```

**Updated code of `selectItemClickHandler` should be:**

```
selectItemClickHandler = (event, index) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const list = [];
            prevState.listItems.map((item, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    item.itemOptionSelector.map(selector => {
                        selector.isSelected = true
                    })
                }
                list.push(item);
            });
            return {
                listItems: list
            };
        });
    };
```

**Here is the complete example where I have changed the above code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class ListExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listItems: [
                {
                    name: 'firstItem',
                    itemOptionSelector: [
                        {id: 1,isSelected: false},
                        {id: 2,isSelected: false},
                        {id: 3,isSelected: false},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'secondItem',
                    itemOptionSelector: [
                        {id: 1,isSelected: false},
                        {id: 2,isSelected: false},
                        {id: 3,isSelected: false},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    selectItemClickHandler = (event, index) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const list = [];
            prevState.listItems.map((item, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    item.itemOptionSelector.map(selector => {
                        selector.isSelected = true
                    })
                }
                list.push(item);
            });
            return {
                listItems: list
            };
        });
    };

    render() {
        const {listItems} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {listItems.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index} className="button" onClick={(event) => {
                        this.selectItemClickHandler(event, index)
                    }}>{item.name}</div>
                })}
                <button onClick={()=>{ console.log(this.state, 'current state') }}>Show State in Console</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post an example because it's not clear what you want to update.

Let's say this is your state.

```js
state = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isSelected: false,
    }
  ]
};
```

And this is how you render your items.

```js
<ul>
  {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={item.id} onClick={this.handleToggle(index)}>
      {item.id} {item.isSelected + ""}
    </li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

Then, your handler needs to look like this.

```js
// pay attention to the handler which creates a closure
handleToggle = index => () => {
  const items = [...this.state.items];

  items[index].isSelected = !items[index].isSelected;

  this.setState({ items });
};
```